# The 'Job' field has a null or empty value in Hangfire

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jobs, hangfire, recurring

In Startup.cs I tried to enqueue recurring job like this:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => Console.WriteLine("test"), Cron.Daily);
```

but received the error:

[image]

Please help to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

My configuration:

```
    //HangFire
    services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration
      .SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170)
      .UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer()
      .UseRecommendedSerializerSettings()
      .UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("HangfireConnection"),
          new SqlServerStorageOptions
          {
              CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
              SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
              QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
              UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = true,
              DisableGlobalLocks = true,
          }
      ));
```

P.S. although 'fire and forget' jobs works.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1576) that says it should be ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Hangfire's source](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/master/src/Hangfire.Core/RecurringJobEntity.cs#L72) indicates that this exception (and message) is thrown when the expression `!recurringJob.ContainsKey("Job") || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJob["Job"])` is true.

```
try
{
    if (!recurringJob.ContainsKey("Job") || String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJob["Job"]))
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("The 'Job' field has a null or empty value");
    }

    Job = InvocationData.DeserializePayload(recurringJob["Job"]).DeserializeJob();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _errors.Add(ex);
}
```

The `recurringJob` Dictionary gets set by the [method `GetAllEntriesFromHash`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/blob/39a62bb8b20d432aaef7113c4c734731ed97499b/src/Hangfire.SqlServer/SqlServerConnection.cs#L435):

```
public override Dictionary<string, string> GetAllEntriesFromHash(string key)
{
    if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key));

    return _storage.UseConnection(_dedicatedConnection, connection =>
    {
        var result = connection.Query<SqlHash>(
            $"select Field, Value from [{_storage.SchemaName}].Hash with (forceseek, readcommittedlock) where [Key] = @key",
            new { key },
            commandTimeout: _storage.CommandTimeout)
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Field, x => x.Value);

        return result.Count != 0 ? result : null;
    });
}
```

So what is probably happening is the `GetAllEntriesFromHash` method is returning `null,` or a Dictionary that doesn't contain the key `Job` (or it's null/whitespace).  But, in [a thread](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/1576#issuecomment-577636705), a Hangfire Contributor commented:

> That's not even a problem, just ignore those exceptions or tell Visual Studio to not to break on them. Hangfire handles a lot of exceptions, and may generate tons of `OperationCanceledException` during shutdown that tells all the background processes that shutdown was requested.

Thus, it seems like this error can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it works yet, but for me the issue was related to the usage of this attribute:

```
[Queue("queue-name")]
public async Task Refresh(PerformContext context)
```

It started to work properly once I removed it from my method.